# can i set/refine the ACL of individual xpage(s) via a theme design element?

Tags: xpages

For an application I need to reduce the access level for an undefined number of persons from author to reader.

The current groups creation is an automated process which I do not want to disturb at this moment.

I was therefor wondering if I can define the xp:aclentry of the xp:acl for individual xpages via a theme design element?

I want to avoid that I have to set this xp:aclentry for each xpage separately.

Comment: If you use it in the theme, wouldn't it get used on every XPage? In which case, why not just put it in the database ACL?

Comment: I have less control over the ACL and the process of adding someone to the ACL is a bit time-consuming. If can make the aclEntry property computed than can I change it whenever I want and have instant effect. In this use case I want to restrict access for certain people (already listed via the ACL) for certain documents.

Comment: Well, if you want to do certain elements, why not put the aclEntry on a custom control, and add it where it is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Why not to put the acl code into a **custom control** and *include* it into every XPage you need it?

Comment: I guess that is more work than trying to establish it via a theme?

Comment: I know but I would like to avoid the custom control approach because the theme approach looks nicer to me. is there a description available what possible things you can/can not set via a theme?

Comment: Ah, I see. You want a complex formula that will pick up whether they ought to be accessing based on some configuration documents. You'd prefer not to even see that on the XPage by having it in the theme. I would still do it via a custom control, as it would be more transparent and easier for the next developer who comes along.